# NodeJS package binary not found in GitHub Actions when using pnpm workspace

Tags: github-actions, bin, pnpm, turborepo, pnpm-workspace

### Overview

I have a monorepo using pnpm workspaces and turborepo. I have one package that's a node binary (`deploy-script`) that I want to call from a package script in another package (`website`).

Locally everything works fine. However, in GitHub actions, the script fails because the binary cannot be found.

**Why does this not work in GitHub actions?**

### Details

#### Command

```bash
pnpm run deploy
```

This calls `turbo run deploy` with the package script I setup in the workspace root.

##### `package.json`

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "turbo run build",
        "deploy": "turbo run deploy",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "turbo": "^1.8.8"
    },
    "packageManager": "pnpm@8.2.0"
}
```

Then in the `apps/website/package.json` deploy script, this calls `deploy-script`.

##### `apps/website/package.json`

```json
{
    "name": "website",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "deploy": "build-script"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "build-script": "workspace:*"
    }
}
```

`deploy-script` is another package defined in this monorepo:

##### `tools/deploy-script/package.json`

```json
{
    "name": "deploy-script",
    "type": "module",
    "bin": ".dist/main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "<build command>"
    }
}
```

#### Error message

```
website:deploy: 
website:deploy: > website@ deploy /home/runner/work/repo/repo/apps/website
website:deploy: > deploy-script
website:deploy: 
website:deploy: sh: 1: deploy-script not found
website:deploy:  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed.
website:deploy: ERROR: command finished with error: command (/home/runner/work/repo/repo/apps/website) pnpm run deploy exited (1)
command (/home/runner/work/repo/repo/apps/website) pnpm run deploy exited (1)
```

This leads me to think that somehow the npm package I want to run as a binary is misconfigured.

#### File structure

```
package.json
turbo.json
pnpm-workspace.yaml
apps/
  website/
    package.json
    main.ts
    .dist/
      main.js -- automatically built before deploying, I checked
tools/
  deploy-script/
    package.json
.github/workflows/ci.yml
```

Note: `.dist/main.js` starts with a shebang as per the NPM docs.

#### Other potentially relevant files

##### `apps/website/package.json`

```json
{
    "name": "website",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "deploy": "build-script"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "build-script": "workspace:*"
    }
}
```

##### `package.json`

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "turbo run build",
        "deploy": "turbo run deploy",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "turbo": "^1.8.8"
    },
    "packageManager": "pnpm@8.2.0"
}
```

##### `turbo.json`

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://turbo.build/schema.json",
    "pipeline": {
        "build": {
            "dependsOn": ["^build"],
            "outputs": [".dist/**"]
        },
        "deploy": {
            "dependsOn": ["^build", "build"]
        },
    }
}
```

##### `pnpm-workspace.yaml`

```yaml
packages:
  - 'apps/**'
  - 'tools/**'
  - 'libs/**'
```

##### `.github/workflows/ci.yml`

```yaml
on:
  - push

jobs:
  check-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18

      - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2
        name: Install pnpm
        id: pnpm-install
        with:
          version: 8
          run_install: false

      - name: Get pnpm store directory
        id: pnpm-cache
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "STORE_PATH=$(pnpm store path)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - uses: actions/cache@v3
        name: Setup pnpm cache
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.pnpm-cache.outputs.STORE_PATH }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pnpm-store-${{ hashFiles('**/pnpm-lock.yaml') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-pnpm-store-

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pnpm install

      - name: Build
        run: pnpm build

      - name: Deploy production
        run: pnpm run deploy
```

I believe I included all necessary details, but let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: you could try to insert a `hash deploy-script` before calling it. and use the relative pathname to see if the file exists and is executable, e.g. with the _file_ utility: `file ./path/to/deploy-script`.

Comment: What would hasing the `deploy-script` help with? Also FYI, I can call the file directly by using `"deploy": "node ./node_modules/deply-script/.dist/main.js"`. However I'd ideally like to not hardcode a path since that creates an abstraction leak–the file structure of the `deploy-script` package is partially (and unnecessarily) leaked to the consumers of this package. For instance, if the `deploy-script` package build pipeline changes in the future, all consumers will need to be updated.

Comment: Yes, all fine, `hash(1)` is purely for the debugging - with a _very_ little exception perhaps in case hashing is necessary. Suggestion was just to put it in as it does check the `PATH`  for the command, which is useful in a pipeline job script, as the system is not kept for debuggin/inspection. Also asking for the longer path (vs. the command name alone) is also purely for trouble shooting. The missing `o` in `.../node_modules/deply-script/...` got lost in translation, right? Otherwise the command _may_ be `deply-script` ....

Comment: Likely only `./node_modules/.bin` is in `PATH` (it's a bit a guessing game, [ref is here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#path)), or perhaps, just check as well `file ./node_moduels/.bin/deploy-script`, it should show whether or not the executable exists. And I'd add a `echo "$PATH" | sed 's/:/\n/g'` line to show the `PATH` for further inspection (GNU sed required).

Comment: Ah I see what you're talking about. Didn't even cross my mind to check the path. Got it working, thanks!

Comment: Ok, so the "fix" was forgetting that the issue was about it not working on CI and testing it locally. However, I did figure out the root of the issue. The `.dist/main.js` files are ignored by git and only generated after a build. So when pnpm initially installs everything, it can't find the file and hence cannot create a binary for it. There may be ways around this, but I've sunk enough time to figuring it out that I'm probably going to move on.

Comment: Heya @Nick, thanks for the feedback. The reasoning sounds clear to me. If it would be me, I'd put that as an answer and if only so that I had documented it for myself answered.  _And:_ It will also allow to mark the question as answered here on site, which is important. I have no problem with that, by the way, if you answer the question yourself. More than that, I would even ask you to do that. Even if it seems to be a small configuration error, now it would not even be obvious that the question was answered to your satisfaction.