# Github actions not finding npm script

Tags: npm, github-actions, package.json, monorepo

I got a monorepo with Lerna 6 and npm where building works fine locally but fails on npm. The structure is the following:

```
package.json
packages
  \- build-scripts
       package.json
  \- package1
       package.json
  \- package2
       package.json
..
```

the root `package.json`:

```json
{
"version": "1.2.3",
"scripts": {
   "build-all": "lerna run build_js --stream"
   ...
},
"devDependencies": {
   "build-scripts": "1.2.3"
},
"workspaces": [
  "./packages/*"
],
...
```

`build-scripts` contains build scripts:

```json
{
"version": "1.2.3",
"bin": {
   "build_js": "./lib/doBuild.js"
   ...
}
...
```

and finally each package uses these to build:

```json
{
"version": "1.2.3",
"scripts": {
   "build": "build_js"
   ...
}
```

The relevant part of the GHA script:

```yaml
name: AUTO Pull Request validation
on: [pull_request]
jobs:
  pr_validation:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        name: Install Node 16
        with:
          node-version: '16'
          cache: 'npm'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build project
        run: npm run build-all
```

This works fine locally with `yarn` and `npm` but on Github actions it does not work with `npm` as our package manager (except if I'd add `build-scripts` as a dependency to all sub-packages..), I get errors like `package1: > build_js sh: 1: build_js: not found` Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: What prevents you adding `build-scripts` as a dependency for those packages that actually depend on it? Or how should otherwise [npm put the `build_js` command into the PATH](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#path) --- assumable the cause of `sh: 1: build_js: not found` --- if you forcefully keep it away from npm?

Comment: And [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11506995/nick) had an npm PATH problem on [tag:github-actions] yesterday and perhaps can share a bit of their findings: [NodeJS package binary not found in GitHub Actions when using pnpm workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75991359/367456)

Comment: @hakre >how should otherwise npm put the build_js command into the PATH? -- `build-scripts` is a dependency of the root package, so its scripts (`build_js`) are put into the root's `node_modules/.bin`. At least locally.

Comment: @hakre > What prevents you adding build-scripts as a dependency for those packages that actually depend on it? Nothing, besides from why should I do this just for GH actions? Some guidance would be cool too how to do this properly. Is there a "recommended" way?

Comment: Yes, we can argue about the Github computer, but I don't think it will listen to our comments here and decide to change mind ;). It's perhaps worth to gather some more information first before finding the clean way, like `file node_modules/.bin/build_js`  on Github, it should show of whether or not the executable has been create by npm (try w/o adding the dependency, with the dependency it sounds to me it is there so the test would not say much) and also check the PATH on Github, it seems that helped @Nick (he didn't share details sadly): `echo "$PATH" | sed 's/:/\n/g'`.

Comment: Please include your relevant GHA workflow in your question. Also, add information that you have verified that those scrips exist at those locations e.g. by adding separate steps and running `ls -l /path/to/script`. Thanks!

Comment: @hakre Its not in `node_modules`:  `Run echo "$(ls -l ./node_modules/.bin/build_js)"
ls: cannot access './node_modules/.bin/build_js': No such file or directory` also `node_modules` is not in the PATH. Why is it there locally?